# add_cascade() missing 1 required positional argument: self (Python: Tkinter error)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to learn how to make a basic GUI in Python with menus.

I have been following a tutorial from 2014 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSm-tq5M-Dc), but it seems that several things have been updated since the tutorial was published.

While I have found workarounds for several of my issues there were a couple I could not figure out.

The biggest issue of which is a `"TypeError: add_cascade() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"`error.

Everything I can find seems to have similar syntax to my code however I cannot seem to run it. I think it is probably a difference in python versions (`I am running python 3.7`) though it is also likely I am just missing something in the tutorial.

```
import tkinter

def doNothing():
    print("DO SOMTHING USEFULL... please")

root=tkinter.Tk()
menu=tkinter.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu=tkinter.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
tkinter.Menu.add_cascade(label="file", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Project...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="New...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_seperator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=doNothing)

editMenu=tkinter.Menu(menu)
tkinter.Menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=doNothing)

root.mainloop()
```

P.S. I know I do not have to put "tkinter." everywhere but I could not seem to get "from Tkinter import *" to work for me.

How do I solve the following error?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want to do is:

```
import tkinter

def doNothing():
    print("DO SOMTHING USEFULL... please")
"TypeError: add_cascade() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" error.
root=tkinter.Tk()
menu=tkinter.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu=tkinter.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="file", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Project...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="New...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=doNothing)

editMenu=tkinter.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=doNothing)

root.mainloop()
```

**"TypeError: add_cascade() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" error.** means that **add_cascade** should be used on instance of tkinter.Menu, not class itself, so you need to create object which will be instance of tkinter.Menu first, you did that but you did not used it to add cascade to it.

edit:

I fixed "sep**e**rator" :D not its correct as "sep**a**rator" ;)

Comment: @ Damian, Thank you for the reply. I tried to execute your code but ran into an "AttributeError: 'Menu' object has no attribute 'add_seperator'" error.  Am I missing something?

Comment: change "sep**e**rator" -> "sep**a**rator" ;) You did typo :) and I have copied this typo xD

Comment: Not checking the manual, but it should probably be `subMenu.add_separator()`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling method `add_cascade` from the Menu class, not from the `menu` object you instantiated with `menu=tkinter.Menu(root)`.

so `tkinter.Menu.add_cascade(label="file", menu=subMenu)` should be `menu.add_cascade(label="file", menu=subMenu)` and `tkinter.Menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)` should be `menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)`.

Comment: @ Powertieke. Thank you for the response. if I am not mistaken, I believe your answer is similar to @Damian's, however, I ran it none the less to the same effect.  I am now receiving a "'Menu' object has no attribute 'add_seperator'" error.  is this a separate error I am receiving or does it stem from the same issue? EDIT: Nevermind. Damian noticed a typo that created the error. I had tried this earlier to no avail and I am kind of mad that I didn't notice this for the past couple hours.

Comment: No worries. We have all been there. :)

Comment: exactly! @AjayM Don't worry, mistakes are the way of experience gaining.